# warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value in for loop

Tags: for-loop, warnings, parentheses

I am working on a program, but am having trouble with a for loop

```
for (int i = N-1; i = 0; i--) {
    guessarray [i] = guess % 10;
    guess /= 10;
}//for
```

With my g++ compiler I keep getting the error "warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value. I understand that I am working backwards in the loop, from low to high, but I don't see how that could be a problem. I have tried putting in parentheses in different places, but it doesn't work. I also know it has nothing to do with the assignment operator since I want to use the assignment operator. The warning is placed directly after N-1.

Comment: If you put the parens around (N-1), does the warning go away?

Comment: No, unfortunately not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is simply calling your attention to the assignment in the for loop.  It is probably doing so because the "for" statement has 3 semicolon-delimited expressions which is rather dense and prone to human error.  By changing

```
for (int i = N-1; i = 0; i--)
```

to

```
for (int i = (N-1); i = 0; i--)
```

you are telling the compiler, that yes you really intended the for the initial value of i to be (N-1).

==================

Note also that there is what appears to be a logic flaw in the condition section of the for loop (the 2nd expresses ion)

You have

```
i = 0;
```

which means the loop will never execute (unless N==1).  I assume your intent was to count down from (N-1) to 0.  Thus You should probably have the following:

```
for (int i = (N-1); i >= 0; i--)  // note the i >= 0 condition
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :) but unfortunately I had already tried that and keep getting the same error....

Comment: I also noticed another problem with your loop.  Your 2nd expression might be incorrect.  Rather than "i = 0;", I think you want "i >= 0".